# How can a description be added to examples individually in JSDoc?

Tags: javascript, documentation, jsdoc

I would like to add a description to each code example individually.

For example:

```
/**
 * Test function, normal description
 *
 * THE DESCRIPTION OF THE EXAMPLE HERE
 * @example
 * fooBar("foo", "bar");
 * 
 * THE DESCRIPTION OF ANOTHER EXAMPLE HERE
 * @example
 * fooBar("bar", "foo", false);
 */ 
function fooBar (param1, param2, param3) {
}
```

How can this be done in JSDoc?

Answer (score 0):

According to the Note at the bottom of http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagExample.

You can build complex example block using HTML markup, and quote your actual example code using `<code>`. You can put the Description part inside the HTML, but outside the `<code>`.

Comment: Thanks! But I was looking for a more "native" approach. Maybe there were a tag in JSDoc or something.